# how to use cast with string function

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to concatenate 'week' with an integer value column from flat file resource on SSIS derived column. this is what I did

```
(("week" + " " +  (DT_WSTR, 20) RIGHT( [CalendarWeek] ,2 ))
```

but I am getting error, please explain with this example or how to use 'right' function with DT_WSTR

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], and read [ask].

Comment: It will help if you paste the error message into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the expression you are using

```
(("week" + " " + (DT_WSTR, 20) RIGHT( [CalendarWeek] ,2 ))
```

Reading left to right: using the literal string week, append a space, concatenate to that the result of casting to a unicode string of length 20, the rightmost two characters of CalendarWeek.

Where could the errors be?

CalendarWeek could be numeric field. `RIGHT` works against a string data type so this would be incorrect. You'd need to cast your data to a string type before performing string manipulation on it.

Logically, you have an error with your concatenation. You are asking for 2 characters from CalendarWeek and then stuffing it into a 20 character wide string.

```
"week" + " " + RIGHT(((DT_WSTR, 20) [CalendarWeek]),2)
```

Assuming I've counted my parenthesis correctly, I believe the expression you are looking for is above.